# XML output using javascript function

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <offer>
        <eventtitle>Football</eventtitle>
        <catdesc>Sport</catdesc>
        <eventprice>10.00</eventprice>
    </offer>
</root>
```

How could i convert this XML to html using a javascript function with a similar approach to this:

(Where the output is stored in the 'retval' var)

```
function displayXML( data ){

    var retval = "";

    // Get XML tags

    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = retval;
}
```

(I basically need to know how to get the XML tags and store them in the 'retval' var)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing nodes in a xml document is similar to accessing nodes in html.

For example:

```
var priceNode=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("eventprice")[0];
var price=priceNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue // gets the text from the eventprice node
```